# How can I use expose.sh to access localhost on Windows as https?

Tags: node.js, https, localhost

I'm trying to access a React app served by nodejs on Windows localhost via https.

```
> expose 3000
http://babd3f.expose.sh is forwarding to localhost:3000
https://babd3f.expose.sh is forwarding to localhost:3000
```

When I try to access either URL on Chrome, I immediately get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at http://babd3f.expose.sh/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

I tried turning Windows Defender off temporarily, but it made no difference.

What else should I try?